# What is the flow type for a zipAll function, such as in lodash/fp?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, flowtype

Even in normal `lodash`, zip's type is declared using overloads, like:

```
zip<A, B>(a1: A[], a2: B[]): Array<[A, B]>;
zip<A, B, C>(a1: A[], a2: B[], a3: C[]): Array<[A, B, C]>;
zip<A, B, C, D>(a1: A[], a2: B[], a3: C[], a4: D[]): Array<[A, B, C, D]>;
zip<A, B, C, D, E>(a1: A[], a2: B[], a3: C[], a4: D[], a5: E[]): Array<[A, B, C, D, E]>;
```

The first line of this satisfies `zip` from `lodash/fp`, but what about `zipAll`?
This function is supposed to take a second order array and basically *transpose* it.

It would look like this for the above limited cases:

```
zipAll<A, B>([A[], B[]]): Array<[A, B]>;
zipAll<A, B, C>([A[], B[], C[]]): Array<[A, B, C]>;
zipAll<A, B, C, D>([A[], B[], C[], D[]]): Array<[A, B, C, D]>;
zipAll<A, B, C, D, E>([A[], B[], C[], D[], E[]]): Array<[A, B, C, D, E]>;
```

Is there no way to define it generally?

Comment: Don't use heterogenuous arrays :-)

Comment: @Bergi, every array here is homogeneous :v
It's the fixed-length tuples who are heterogenous.

Real heterogenous arrays do seem to be broken atm.
Seems like `Array<number>` is not a subtype of `Array<number|[number,string]>` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't much of an answer, but: no there isn't. This would require some sort of meta-programming layer.

You can see very similar patterns applied in other languages, for example Haskell. Even though Haskell's type system can be considered more sophisticated, it doesn't have overloads, and `zip` is [implemented for different sized tuples](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:zip) using new names: `zip`, `zip3`, `zip4` etc. In general, Haskell's Prelude stops at 7 arguments when defining these types of thing, since the code generally becomes unreadable by that point anyway.